# Drag and drop features of a WMS service using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, wms

I have a WMS service, which is a point layer. Is it possible to drag and drop features of a this service layer through OpenLayers?

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you wish to do? please see this post on tips to improve this question: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question

Comment: I have a geoserver service with attached postgres table,which contains point data.when any user is marking any point on the map it is getting updated in that table.Now I want to provide editing option for the mapped points,I am able to edit the attributes in the postgres table,but is it possible to change the location of particular point on the map (like drag and drop example of open layers).

Comment: Please use the edit button beneath your question to revise it with these additional details.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but you need to have the layer also available as WFS feature type. Then you can do something like http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html. Note: that example shows editing of a polygon layer, but you can do the same with a point layer. The component used to drag/drop points is `OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to drag points from a WMS point layer.  A WMS layer is **an image**. The input data may be a vector point data source (shapefile for example) but the WMS layer delivered to the web browser through your OpenLayers client is an image.